# LINQ method to join every n elements in a series by a function, and then re-aggregate those results into a new list?

Tags: c#, linq

Not sure if the question is titled clearly, but here goes. I have some rather messy code in my ASP.NET MVC 3 app to wrap every 2 (but make this configurable from 1-n) items in a list in a div tag when they are printed out. I'd like to create a LINQ function like so:

```
// Can't think of a better name
IEnumerable<V> FormattedSubsetList<T, V>(IEnumerable<T> items, int every = 2, [delegate to a method to join the N elements])
{
}
```

Sorry if this is kind of complicated... I'll try an example. Let's say I have a list of `Widget`. I want to print out the names of all my widgets (let's say I have 7) and I want every 2 widgets to be inside a div. So if I have...

```
var list = new List<Widget>();
list.Add(new Widget() { Name = "One" });
//... you get the picture
list.Add(new Widget() { Name = "Seven" });

IEnumerable<string> newList = FormattedSubsetList<Widget, string>(list, 2, (one, two) => (return "<div>" + string.Join(" ", one.Name, two.Name) + "</div>");
string finalString = string.Join(string.Empty, newList);
// finalString == <div>One Two</div><div>Three Four</div><div>Five Six</div><div>Seven</div>
```

I apologize if anything is unclear but I simply don't know what sort of thing this is called and have no idea how to go about implementing it. I know my LINQ syntax is a little off in some places too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two extension methods that will do exactly what you need. `Split` method is reusable, it simply splits any IEnumerable into a list of enumerables so each subenumerable has not more than `size` elements. The second method `ToFormattedList` is the customer method that does what you asked for.

```
public static class Extenstions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TRestul> ToFormattedList<TElement, TRestul>(
        this IEnumerable<TElement> source,
        int count,
        Func<List<TElement>, TRestul> formatter)
    {
        return source.Split(count).Select(arg => formatter(arg.ToList()));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
    {
        var i = 0;
        return
            from element in source
            group element by i++ / size into splitGroups
            select splitGroups.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
var list = new List<Widget> { new Widget { Name = "One" }, new Widget { Name = "Two" }, new Widget { Name = "Three" }, new Widget { Name = "Four" }, new Widget { Name = "Five" }, new Widget { Name = "Six" }, new Widget { Name = "Seven" }, new Widget { Name = "Eight" } };

var newList = list.ToFormattedList(2, args => "<div>" + args[0].Name + args[1].Name + "</div>");
var finalString = string.Join(string.Empty, newList);
// finalString = <div>OneTwo</div><div>ThreeFour</div><div>FiveSix</div><div>SevenEight</div>
```

However, there will be a problem if list has odd number of elements, because args[1] will throw exception on the last element. So you can do:

```
var newList = list.ToFormattedList(2, args => "<div>" + string.Join(" ", args.Select(arg => arg.Name)) + "/<div>");
```

Comment: Being able to handle odd numbers of elements without extra checks is important. I'll settle for Matt's function and a nested foreach loop. Great example though, shows how amazing and powerful LINQ can be...

Comment: @Jake Petroules - hmm.. interesting. You asked for the function with certain definition. I gave you this function. The function is doing exactly what you need and asked for, but you are choosing an answer without such function. This is rather discouraging.

Comment: @Jake Petroules - I updated with the example how you can easily handle lists with odd element number. I thought that you need to be able to format each element differently, this is why I used `StringBuilder` to show that you can format the output as you want.

Comment: You are correct. I neglected to state the odd number handling was of importance. Thank you for this code.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the grouping in a simple Select call. Here's a small console app that kind of does what you want:

```
var list = new List<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) list.Add("Widget #" + (i + 1));

var groupedWidgets = list
    .Select((w, i) => new { Widget = w, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => (int)(x.Index / 2));

foreach (var g in groupedWidgets)
{
    Console.WriteLine("<div>");
    foreach (var w in g)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  " + w.Widget);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("</div>");
}
```

So I'm grouping by "Index / 2" as an int, which means that items 1 and 2 will end up together, then items 3 and 4 etc. Changing the "2" to a "3" groups the widgets in threes.

Does that make sense?

**Update** Here's a generic function that returns a list of grouped elements:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupSelect<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int groupSize)
    {
        return list
            .Select((t, i) => new { t, i })
            .GroupBy(x => (int)(x.i / groupSize), x => x.t);
    }
}
```

So now you can just write:

```
foreach (var g in list.GroupSelect(3))
{
    Console.WriteLine("<div>");
    foreach (var w in g)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  " + w);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("</div>");
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful, thank you. But how can I make this into a resuable function, though? I don't know how to get the Widget from that anonymous type and therefore can't declare a proper return type (which should be `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`?) for the function.

Comment: @Jake I don't know if you need to wrap it in a function, given that it's just a call to Select and GroupBy. However, I'll update the answer with an example method.

Comment: I just think list.ToGroupedList(2) is much clearer and would rather use a function than copy/paste a particular sequence of code around. However, this is *exactly* what I need, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension method that should meet your needs.

```
  public static IEnumerable<string> FormatSubsetList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int every, Func<IEnumerable<T>,string> formatter)
  {
     List<T[]> list = new List<T[]> ();
     int index = 0;
     foreach (T i in input)
     {
        T[] array;
        if (index % every == 0)
           list.Add (array = new T[every]);
        else
           array = list[list.Count - 1];
        array[index++ % every] = i;
     }
     return list.Select(t => t.Where (i => i != null)).Select(formatter);
  }
  static Program()
  {
     List<Widget> widgets = new List<Widget> ();
     Func<IEnumerable<Widget>,string> formatter = 
        items => items.Aggregate (new StringBuilder ("<div>"), (sb,w) => sb.Append(" ").Append (w.Name), sb => sb.Append ("</div>").ToString ());
     widgets.FormattedSubsetList(3, formatter);
  }
```