# How do I do a group my select by a fixed number using Linq to objects?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

```
data.Select(object=> string.Format("<a>{0}</a>", object.LinkText))      
.Select(html => string.Format("<div>{0}</div>", html))    
.Aggregate((running, next) => running + next);
```

I have this query which basically turns some objects into html-markup. What I can´t seem to achieve is that the second select should only be run for every (fixed number) 3 elements in the first select. I wan´t my ouput to be something like this:

```
<div><a>xxx</a><a>yyy</a><a>zzz</a></div>
<div><a>ååå</a>....</div>
```

Please help me avoid a for-loop!

Comment: There's an overload of Select that can include an index. `.Select((item, index) => ...)`. Perhaps group on `index / 3`. Of course, a loop might make your code entirely more obvious. Try it both ways, figure out which is more readable for the *given* scenario.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406168/linq-method-to-join-every-n-elements-in-a-series-by-a-function-and-then-re-aggr

Comment: I believe you can leverage MoreLINQ `Batch()` operator but not 100% sure, [see here](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs)

Comment: That was more or less what I did Anthony, thanks. Stu: Thanks for the link, would have worked but I didn´t care for the extra extension methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To group by 3, use this LINQ query:

```
    var data = new[] {"quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};
    var res = data
        .Select((s, i) => new { Link = string.Format("<a>{0}</a>", s), Index = i })
        .GroupBy(p => p.Index/3)
        .Select(g => string.Format("<div>{0}</div>", string.Join("", g.Select(v => v.Link))));
    foreach (var re in res) {
        Console.WriteLine(re);
    }
```

The output of this program looks like this:

```
<div><a>quick</a><a>brown</a><a>fox</a></div>
<div><a>jumps</a><a>over</a><a>the</a></div>
<div><a>lazy</a><a>dog</a></div>
```

Note how this code uses `string.Join` instead of a slower `Aggregate`.
Of course since you use some other objects instead of strings, you will need to replace `string.Format("<a>{0}</a>", s)` with `string.Format("<a>{0}</a>", s.LinkText)`.

Comment: Great! Thanks dasblinkenlight, this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Add in the after the first Select `.Take(3)`

Comment: probably also need to do an `html.Aggregate` to get it from `IEnumerable<string>` to `string`.

Comment: He's not interested in 3 items, he needs groups of 3 items. `Take(n)` is not going to be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you the desired result:

```
 var data = new List<String>();
            data.BreakIntoChunks(3).Select(html => string.Format("<div>{0}</div>", String.Join("", (html.Select(
                item => string.Format("<a>{0}</a>", item))).ToArray())));
        ...

    public static class EnumerableExt
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TRecord>> BreakIntoChunks<TRecord>(this IEnumerable<TRecord> items,
                                                                                 int chunkSize)
        {
            int itemCount = 0;
            var processedItems = new List<TRecord>();
            foreach (TRecord record in items)
            {
                ++itemCount;
                processedItems.Add(record);
                if (itemCount%chunkSize == 0)
                {
                    yield return processedItems;
                    processedItems.Clear();
                }
            }
            if (processedItems.Count != 0)
            {
                //Because- return the items which are not multiple of chunkSize
                yield return processedItems;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: The result is generated in single iteration. That's the magic of yield return!